# Why can't I see specific task execution in Yarn while using H2O on hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, h2o

I ran H2O on yarn according to the official requirements:

```
http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/11/index.html
```

This is my command:

```
cd ~/opt/h2o-3.18.0.8-hdp2.6
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output /user/spark/h2o-3_output
```

And the h2o cluster is running successfully.
[image]

But after I run the example flow in the h2o-flow, I didn't see any calculations related to the GBM algorithm, only H2O itself.
[image]

I thought I would see something like this.This was the result of a decision tree flow diagram using RapidMiner, which presents each specific task.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the expected behavior from H2O.

H2O just uses YARN to get containers for the H2O worker nodes to run.  Once those containers are up, H2O has CPU and memory resources to work, and doesn't interact with YARN anymore.  So the YARN Resource Manager knows that H2O is up, like you see, but doesn't know any details.

To see details, go to the H2O Flow Web UI (as directed in the "Open H2O Flow" message in the output above).  The Admin->Jobs menu item shows you what you are looking for.